# Evaluating a sequential limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

If $\lambda_n=\int_0^1\frac{dt}{(1+t)^n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$
then

1. $\lambda_n$ does not exist for some $n$.
2. $\lambda_n$ exists for every $n$ and the sequence is unbounded.
3. $\lambda_n$ exists for every $n$ and the sequence is bounded.
4. $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\lambda_n)^{1/n}=1$.

I know that 1) and 2) will not be correct. But I am little confused about 4). Will it be correct?

Comment: What is $v_n$, or whatever the exponent in 4) is ?

Comment: it is {lamda n} and exponent is $\frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that $\lambda_1=\ln 2$ and for $n>1$,
$$\lambda_n=\int_0^1\frac{dt}{(1+t)^n}=\left[-\frac{1}{(n-1)(1+t)^{n-1}}\right]_0^1=\frac{1}{n-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right).$$
Hence
$$\frac{1}{2(n-1)}\leq \lambda_n\leq \frac{1}{n-1}.$$
What is $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\lambda_n)^{1/n}$?

Comment: $\lambda_1$ is $log2$@Robert Z

Comment: I am confused about the limit

Comment: @cmi Note that $n^{1/n}\to 1$.

Comment: so limit will be 1?

Comment: @cmi Yes. Are you able to show it?

Comment: @cmi Any more doubts?